# Converting a string to a list of key-value pairs

Tags: c++, c++03

I'm trying to convert a string (here after called `input`) into a vector of key-value pairs, all in C++03 (cannot use C++11, cannot use Boost libs).

The string in question can contain whitespaces. A comma (`,`) delimits key-value pairs and the equals sign (`=`) separates the key from the value.
A sample string (also in the code could be: `"ab=xy z,time a=1s"`. Notice the lack of a final `,`.

Any improvement is most welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


struct Flag_name_value {
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};

std::istringstream& operator>>(std::istringstream& iss, Flag_name_value& fnv)
{
    char ch; 
    std::ostringstream oss;

    while (iss >> std::noskipws >> ch) {
        std::cout << ch << "\n";
        switch(ch) {
            case('='):
                fnv.name = oss.str();
                oss.str("");
                break;
            case(','):
                fnv.value = oss.str();
                oss.str("");
                break;
            default:
                oss << ch; 
                break;
        }   

        if (!fnv.name.empty() && !fnv.value.empty())
        {   
            return iss;
        }   
    }   

    // We end here if the string didn't end with ','
    fnv.value = oss.str();
    return iss;
}

int main () {

    std::string input("ab=xy z,time a=1s");

    std::istringstream iss(input);

    std::vector<Flag_name_value> flags;
    while (true) {
        Flag_name_value f;
        iss >> f;
        flags.push_back(f);
        if (!iss) break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can use `std::getline` to extract key-value pairs from the original string. This can be done by passing `,` as a delimiter to `std::getline`:

```
while (std::getline(iss, token, ',')) { ... }
```

Notice that you don't have to perform any checks on the stream this way. Once `std::getline` will reach the end of the stream it will set the `eofbit` on it, so the loop condition will evaluate to `false` on next iteration.

Next, use can use `std::string::find` to find an index of the occurrence of the `=` character in strings filled by `std::getline`:

```
size_t pos = token.find('=');
```

After that use can use this index to extract two substrings - your key and your value:

```
flag.name    = token.substr(0, pos);
flag.value   = token.substr(pos + 1);
```

Notice that you can omit the second argument of `std::string::substr`, since it has the default value of `std::string::npos`. This value is very huge (in fact, it equals to the maximum value that can be represented by a size type of `std::string`), but `std::string::substr` never reads past the end of line, so everything will be good.

Tie all this together and you'll get a small and readable solution:

```
std::string input("ab=xy z,time a=1s");
std::istringstream iss(input);

std::vector<Flag_name_value> flags;

std::string token;
Flag_name_value flag;
while (std::getline(iss, token, ',')) {
    size_t pos   = token.find('=');
    flag.name    = token.substr(0, pos);
    flag.value   = token.substr(pos + 1);
    flags.push_back(flag);
}
```

Comment: Will throw `std::out_of_range` if any extracted token does not contain an `=`-sign.

Comment: It will throw `std::out_of_range` if the first argument (that is a starting position) is larger than the size of the string. If extracted string does not contain the `=` character, `std::string::find` will return `std::string::npos`, which is obviously larger than the size of the string.

Comment: Yes. Just though you might want to note that down.

Comment: That's just awesome. Short, yet terse and really easy to understand. Thanks!